# Is there any tool to measure speed of laptop and test laptop hanging before and after adding 8GB RAM?

Tags: cpu-speed, hp-laptop, computer-behavior

My hp laptop having core i3 plus 4GB of RAM hangs on running one chrome browser with some tabs plus visual studio 2015. I just upgrade my laptop from 4GB of RAM to 4+8 GB of RAM. Now I want to measure/judge how much difference in processing speed and how many heavy applications I can run in parallel. Can anyone please tell me a way to measure how much efficiency I have gotten in terms of speed and capacity of parallel processing? Is there tool for laptop hang testing?

Comment: Your processing speed won't increase, since your CPU, is exactly the same.

Comment: Question edited. My basic problem is laptop hangs on running chrome and visual studio for some time. Is there tool for laptop hang testing?

Comment: If you still have that problem, even with 12 GB of system memory, those processes were not hanging because of your memory usage.

Comment: they could be hanging because of a memory misconfiguration (SPD) in the BIOS. If the two sets of memory report different capabilities, the BIOS must choose something, occasionally, it chooses wrong. Often this will work in general, but certain processes will show side effects.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I think you just have a weak CPU. You shouldn't hang from running 1 Chrome browser. If your computer is already hanging from that, adding more RAM isn't going to do you any good. If anything, you'll just cause more hanging by having more applications open and trying to do more multitasking. ** Is there tool for laptop hang testing?** Before you start diving deep, be sure to check the shallow waters. Open up task manager, and watch your CPU usage when doing things. If it's at 100%, see what process is utilizing it most.

Comment: Verify the system is running a 64-bit operating system.  It won't help with the performance with Visual Studio but will help with performance and security with Chrome.  Visual Studio is a 32-bit application.  Of course if the real problem is your CPU, switchting to a 64-bit OS, won't solve your problem.

Comment: @DrZoo: CPU usage is around 7%. Memory gets up to 74% with 10-15 tabs in Chrome browser and MS visual studio 2015 after running these processes for one-two hour.

Comment: @Ramhound: My system has Windows 7 x64. Hanging problem occurs after running chrome and visual studio for one-two hours.

Comment: If you still have these problems with 12 GB of memory have a memory leak

Comment: Run a memory test to make sure you have no hardware issues. From there, it could be software/file corruption or just low performing CPU.

Answer (score 1):

AIDA64 has a memory stress test, but since I don't think you've changes the RAM clock speed, the change you'll see will probably be linear with the size increase.

Comment: Question edited. Is there tool for "laptop-hang" testing?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Hiren Tools](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), they have a collection of a lot of very useful tools.  You can get GoldMemory 5.07, Memtest86+ 4.20, MemTest 1.0 and S&M Stress Test 1.9.1 (just to name a few) from their website, to do testing.  Hope this helps!